# MySQL "AND" statement issue

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have 2 table (sample below)

```
aTable
-------------------------------------------------
name    |   datein                  |   dateout
test    |   2016-10-10 00:00:00     |   null --->> This one
test2   |   2016-10-12 00:00:00     |   null
-------------------------------------------------

bTable
------------------------------------------------------------
name    |   datein                  |   dateout
test    |   2016-05-05 00:00:00     |   2016-06-06 00:00:00 
test    |   2016-10-10 00:00:00     |   null --->> This one
test2   |   2016-10-12 00:00:00     |   2016-10-13 00:00:00
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract the data where both `name`, `datein` are **equal** and `dateout` is **null**

I am using the query below, but I get empty response.

```
SELECT name,datein 
FROM aTable 
WHERE (name = 'test' AND dateout IS NULL) AND 
      (SELECT name FROM bTable WHERE name = 'test' AND dateout IS NULL)
```

Is there any point I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `EXISTS` to your query:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.datein 
FROM aTable AS t1
WHERE (t1.name = 'test' AND t1.dateout IS NULL) AND 
      EXISTS(SELECT name 
             FROM bTable AS t2
             WHERE t2.name = 'test' AND 
                   t2.datein = t1.datein AND
                   t2.dateout IS NULL)
```

or, without supplying a specific value for `name` field:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.datein 
FROM aTable AS t1
WHERE t1.dateout IS NULL AND 
      EXISTS(SELECT name 
             FROM bTable AS t2
             WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND 
                   t2.datein = t1.datein AND
                   t2.dateout IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  SELECT name,datein,dateout FROM(select * from atable union select * from btable)as tt 
where tt.name ='test' and tt.dateout is null;
```

Comment: why try this? What does it change? What does it do? Explain your answer.